# Linux Centos 6 becomes unavailable from time to time - OS&network issue

Tags: centos, connection

I am encountering following problem. There is one server (DL160 G5) running Centos 6.3 with default kernel 2.6.32-220.2.1.el6.x86_64 - at this point I'd like to add that issue appeared also at older version - 6.1 and older kernel (do not remember exactly which version).
There is cPanel installed and from time to time it becomes unavailable (network connection). What I've checked is (via KVMoIP):

- load average is completely normal
- it does not lack memory or disk space when problem occurs
- no console notifications
- checked all access logs and there is no sign that it can be caused by a client script
- cannot even access local interface (127.0.0.1) or main IP address
- running tcpdump I can only see packets arriving to server - no responses
- all services seem to be running properly (mail,sql,http,ssh)
- checked crontab and all clients' crontabs too
- network port utilisation is low ( up to several Mbits)
- arriving packet rate is low - hundreds per second (according to tcpdump)
- console (via kvmoip) works fine, no lags
- there is no conntrack at this server
- there is no ipv6 at this server
- flushing iptables, unloading modules does not resolve problem
- restarting network does not resolve problem, no errors appear
- it also occurs when two sepearate networks are configured (and multiple gateways) as well    as one IP, one default gw and one network is configured - so it seems network configuration independent
- it seems to repeat randomly (load,packet rate,bandwith usage,load independent)
- checked server with different rootkit detection tools - it seems to be clean
- server has been rebooted, it did not change anything
- there are no interface errors
- it apperas randomly can be once a week or several times per day

It usually works fine after 1-15 minutes. What I can also check? It is definitely OS issue - there is traffic at interface only in one direction when problem occurs, can not even ping loopback. Any ideas? Recommended checks? Anything I did not checked above.

Answer (score 2):

It's a long shot, but I recently had a problem where at random intervals certain systems would experience very high "SYSTEM" cpu time, which was bad enough that clustering tools would assume the system was dead and issue halts and the like.

During your problem try `top` and hit `1` to expand the CPUs, and have a look at whether one or more processors are indicating strange behavior.

This is what it might look like if this problem is in effect.  Note the high "sy" value.

```
Cpu0  : 16.7%us, 25.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 50.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  8.3%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  : 28.6%us, 42.9%sy,  0.0%ni, 28.6%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu2  :  6.0%us, 11.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 80.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  2.3%si,  0.0%st
Cpu3  : 20.0%us, 60.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 20.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
```

You can also run `dstat -talm` (maybe background it and redirect to a file) to get per-second statistics which might help with diagnosing the issue in case you aren't able to be looking at it right it starts.

Note that, for my problem, I ended up working with Red Hat support for weeks, and eventually just tried installing a more recent patch-version of the kernel, which was the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS or any variation of Linux does not do that just for fun. There's an underlying hardware issue.

My guess is that your server is a VMware or other virtualized guest and the problem occurs while a guest snapshot is taken.

Your bullet point list was quite long, but it did not mention logs. Anything interesting in `dmesg` output or under `/var/log`?

Comment: It is not virtualized machine. It is standalone server - HP DL160 G5 running 'almost' default Centos with cPanel installed. I've forgot to write about logs - it was first thing I've checked. Unfortunately, each time there is absolutely no interesting info provided by dmesg, syslog, secure etc. In general, I've checked all logs from /var/log, as well as cpanel access logs and apache error logs. I've found nothing 'special' or suspicious. It is why I ask here, maybe someone has some more suggestions what I can check, some kind of tools to use, some other low-level OS checks.

Comment: Oh, HP. I presume you have the latest firmware installed.